# Adding search functionality using vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to add a search filter to my application using vue.js.

```
Error:
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.js:634
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="search">
<input type="text" name="Filter" class="input--search" v-model="query" v-on:keyup="tableFilter" placeholder="Filter By Name">
</div>
```

Vue.js

```
var userId = '@(user.Guid.ToString())';
var tenant = '@(Model.Tenant.RowKey)';
var classId = '@(Model.CLClass.Guid.ToString())';
var students = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Students));
var addStudentUrl = '@Url.Action("AddStudents", "Classes", new { id = Model.CLClass.Guid })';
var frameAccounts = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FrameAccounts));
var allUsers = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AllUsers));
var classHub = $.connection.classHub;
$.connection.hub.qs = { tenant: tenant, userid: userId, classid: classId, name: '@($"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}")' };
var vclass = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        classHub: classHub,
        classId: '@(Model.CLClass.Guid.ToString())',
        userId: '@(user.Guid.ToString())',
        user: '@($"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}")',
        tenant: tenant,
        students: students,
        form: {
            selectionIds: []
        },
        frameAccounts: frameAccounts,
        tenant: tenant,
        messages: [],
        message: '',
        showModal: false,
        users: allUsers,
        addStudentUrl: addStudentUrl,
        query: ''
    },
    computed: {
        tableFilter() {
            console.log("Started typing in search box")
            //return this.users.findBy(this.users, this.query, 'LastName')
            if (this.query == '') return this.users

            return this.users.filter(user => {
                return user.LastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.query.toLowerCase())
            })
        }
    },
```

Comment: I am using Vue.JS version 2

Answer (score 0):

You are using **computed** prop as function. Just move it to the **methods** section of your component. And also you probably will be interested in an event props so you should declare tableFilter as:

```
methods: {
  tableFilter(e) {
   /// your keyup handler code here
  }
}
```